# how to set activatedRouter just run once?

Tags: angular

I try to get data as string in the url, and I try to use activatedRoute to do the task

here is my app components:

```
  this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((value)=>{
    this.id=parseInt(value['name']);

    this.userId = this.id;

  });
```

after console.info(this.id) :   NaN --> '12345678'

but i just need '12345678' T_T

maybe it need to set some timeout ??

i try to push(this.id) into array, i thought i can do array[1]:NaN, array[2]:'12345678' but fail .

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
this.id = parseInt(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams.name);
```

Comment: just give me NaN , the id is gone =.=

Comment: i guse onit does not catch url when the page start , so return NaN,  after some how it finally catch the url, so return the data again ?????

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is set in `ngOnInit`. It runs multiple times if view changes, or data changes... and could be many other reasons. I suggest to check for `id` and then make the call. Also, unsubscribe if you do not want to look for changes in the data afterwards.

```
if (!this.id) {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((value) => {
        this.id = parseInt(value['name']);

        this.userId = this.id;

    }).unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Shouldnt you unsubscribe inside the callback? Moreover, in case you want some vlues here and now, you should use route snapshot, not async subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [`first()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/first.html) operator to achieve this if you really only need the first value. Otherwise, use [`filter()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html).

```js
this.activatedRoute.queryParams
.pipe(
    first((value) => value['name'] && value['name'].length > 0)
)
.subscribe((value) => {
    this.id = parseInt(value['name']);

    this.userId = this.id;
});
```